How to add padding to the right side of an overflowing div
If you shrink your window until the div's are overflowing and you have to scroll, the padding on the right side disappears. Any ideas on how to add padding to the right side? I've tried moving the padding from .container to .flex-container, but it didn't work.


.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
flex-shrink: 0;
 background: #e5e7eb;
 padding: 1rem;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




If we add some borders we start to get a clue why this is happening. The padding of the outer container (including the padding on the right side) does constrain the position of the inner container, but the contents of the inner container overflow to the right.


.container {
  padding: 2rem;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #e5e7eb;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



It’s really the inner container which needs to manage the overflow, not the outer container. If we move the overflow style to the inner container, the problem is resolved:


.container {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #e5e7eb;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Or simply combine the two wrappers into one, and it works too:


.container {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #e5e7eb;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Test1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Test1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Test1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Test1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Test1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Test1</h2>
  </div>
</div>




Hope this solves your problem, below are very simple steps:
1 - I have hidden the overflow of the parent div, so that the padding remains the same with the parent div.
2 - Also added overflow to child div so it can be scrolled.


.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #e5e7eb;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Test1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




@tacoshy Thanks, I have now edited the steps I changed there, please check now.

I hope I understood your problem correctly
If you add this to your code, a space will be added at the end of the scroll.
.flex-container:last-child {
   margin-right: 8px;
}‍‍‍

